# Why do I get this compiler error when trying to include Allegro headers on a Mac?

Tags: c, allegro

I ran `brew install allegro` on OSX while following [this tutorial](https://wiki.allegro.cc/index.php?title=Example_ExHello).

My code looks like this:

```
include <allegro.h>

int main(void) { 
  if (allegro_init() != 0)
     return 1;

  /* set up the keyboard handler */
  install_keyboard(); 

  /* set a graphics mode sized 320x200 */
  if (set_gfx_mode(GFX_AUTODETECT, 320, 200, 0, 0) != 0) {
     if (set_gfx_mode(GFX_SAFE, 320, 200, 0, 0) != 0) {
   set_gfx_mode(GFX_TEXT, 0, 0, 0, 0);
   allegro_message("Unable to set any graphic mode\n%s\n", allegro_error);
   return 1;
     }
  }

  /* set the color palette */
  set_palette(desktop_palette);

  /* clear the screen to white */
  clear_to_color(screen, makecol(255, 255, 255));

  /* you don't need to do this, but on some platforms (eg. Windows) things
   * will be drawn more quickly if you always acquire the screen before
   * trying to draw onto it.
   */
  acquire_screen();

  /* write some text to the screen with black letters and transparent background */
  textout_centre_ex(screen, font, "Hello, world!", SCREEN_W/2, SCREEN_H/2, makecol(0,0,0), -1);

  /* you must always release bitmaps before calling any input functions */
  release_screen();

  /* wait for a keypress */
  readkey();

  return 0;
}
```

And I get these error messages:

```
1.c:1:1: error: unknown type name 'include'
include <allegro.h>
^
1.c:1:9: error: expected identifier or '('
include <allegro.h>
        ^
2 errors generated.
make: *** [1] Error 1
```

Comment: Try http://stackoverflow.com. This is not a game-programming question.

Comment: Somehow setting up tools is not a game programming question.

Comment: Is Allegro a game-specific technology?

Comment: "Allegro is a software library for video game development.[2][3][4] The functionality of the library includes support for basic 2D graphics, image manipulation, text output, audio output, MIDI music, input and timers, as well as additional routines for fixed-point and floating-point matrix arithmetic, Unicode strings, file system access, file manipulation, data files, and 3D graphics."
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Allegro_(software)

Answer (score 2):

`include <allegro.h>`

This isn't valid; preprocessor directives start with a `#`. You probably meant to be typing `#include <allegro.h>`

Your error indicates this:

> `1.c:1:1: error: unknown type name 'include'
>   include <allegro.h>`

You can read this is the compiler reading `include` as a type, but there's no type named `include` that it knows about so it complains. This should make you question why the compiler *thinks* `include` is a type, because you should know you're trying to use the preprocessor to paste in the content of the Allego header file. Not name a type.